# How to perform a huge git rebase in small batches?

Tags: git, gstreamer

I am using gstreamer version 1.18 for my project which contains several individual repositories. For example:

- gst-plugins-base
- gst-plugins-good
- gst-plugins-bad
- gst-plugins-ugly

All of the above individual git repos are part of the gstreamer project.
Locally, we have some private commits in those individual repositories. For example, 700 commits

Recently, the gstreamer project has been converted into mono repo. All the sub repos are merged together and formed as a single repo.

Now, we would like to upgrade our local gstreamer version to 1.22 from 1.18. For that, first, we were converted our gstreamer 1.18 into a mono repo using script provided by the gstreamer community. Then we tried to rebase this 1.18 local branch with 1.22.

We see a total of 4000 commits that have to be rebased. Right now, I am using the following command to perform rebase:

```
git rebase -i <branch_1.22>
```

Is there any way to split these 4000 commits into chunks and work on them in batches?

Comment: I imagine these individual repositories have been integrated to the central mono-repo by applying some history rewriting script -- do you know what script that is ? if someone applies the same rewriting script on their local clone of a subrepo, they should have a history which matches the one in the mono-repo, and be able to merge or rebase with the correct merge-bases.

Comment: I used the merge script to merge all individual repos into the single repository at local side. I assume now, the directory structure of my local repo is matching with remote mono repo but the only problem is I have some additional commit in the local repo which are causing conflicts during the interactive rebase.

Comment: @LeGEC Do you have any idea how the rebase commit list is generated? I couldn't copy the commits from the rebase interactive terminal.

Comment: the list of commits itself is just `git log --oneline --reverse <branch_1.22>..HEAD`. Beware: this list is flat and will not preserve merge commits if you happen to have some.